# Google Cloud Datastore transactional task enqueuing

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In the Google App Engine docs, it shows [how to include enqueuing a message on a queue as part of a datastore transaction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/transactions#transactional_task_enqueuing). I use GCP but run services on GKE not app engine. Is it possible to get this functionality using the non-app engine datastore and pubsub services?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not currently possible to do transactions between Cloud Datastore and Cloud Pub/Sub. You'd have to come up with a custom 2-phase system to do this.